# NicEdit Picture uploaded but shows blank image in editor

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, nicedit

I have a problem regarding the nicEditor for textarea.

When i upload image in niceeditor from local storage image will be uploaded to folder and also database but doesen't showing in textarea.
[image]

As you can see in image text editor shows blank image.
my code is as follow.

```
  var nicUploadOptions = {
        buttons : {
            'upload' : {name : 'Upload Image', type : 'nicUploadButton'}
        }

    };
    var nicUploadButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({nicURI:"image.php" and more..
    nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicUploadOptions);
```

And PHP Code is as follow

```
<?php
//Check if we are getting the image
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        //Get the image array of details
        $img = $_FILES['image'];       
        //The new path of the uploaded image, rand is just used for the sake of it
        $path = "upload/" . rand().$img["name"];
        //Move the file to our new path
        move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'],$path);
        //Get image info, reuiqred to biuld the JSON object
        $data = getimagesize($path);
        //The direct link to the uploaded image, this might varyu depending on your script location    
        $link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"."/nicedit/".$path;
        //Here we are constructing the JSON Object
        $res = array("data" => array( "link" => $link, "width" => $data[0], "height" => $data[1]));
        //echo out the response :)
        echo json_encode($res);
}
?>
```

Image will be successfully upload to folder and database.

Comment: Check your console or inspect img to see what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Following Sollution

```
 line starting with nicURI:"http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json" 
    Replace with

    nicURI:"image.php"
```

And PHP Code is

```
<?php
//Check if we are getting the image
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        //Get the image array of details
        $img = $_FILES['image'];       
        //The new path of the uploaded image, rand is just used for the sake of it
        $path = "upload/" . rand().$img["name"];
        //Move the file to our new path
        move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'],$path);
        //Get image info, reuiqred to biuld the JSON object
        $data = getimagesize($path);
        //The direct link to the uploaded image, this might varyu depending on your script location    
        $link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"."/nicedit/".$path;
        //Here we are constructing the JSON Object
         $res = array("data" => array( "link" => $link, "width" => $data[0], "height" => $data[1]));                          
                    ));
        //echo out the response :)
        echo json_encode($res);
}
?>
```

DONE ! Now i try uploading something and it would go directly to your server

I reffer http://manzzup.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/customize-nicedit-image-upload-to.html .